# What is the syntax of `i++` in Matlab

Tags: matlab, syntax, increment

Is there a shortcut statement that would do what C code `i++` would do? (that is to increase `i` by `1`)?

Of course i do not mean the obvious `i = i + 1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot do this in Matlab. To increment a variable, you must use `i = i + 1;`.

---

**Edit** - If you were *really* desperate for something like this, you could define a function that looked like

```
function increment(x)
    evalin('caller', sprintf('%s = %s + 1;', x, x));
end
```

and call it like this

```
>> x = 1;
>> increment x;
>> x
x =
    2
```

however this would be (a) confusing and (b) slow.

Comment: Sorry. `i++` is more cool. :-) And thank you, almost forgot.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I think that `i = i + 1` is more performant.

Comment: I'm not sure @Chris really intends anyone to use his example function, but if anyone does, make sure to only use `increment x` rather than `increment(x)`. Actually, try both, get confused, then use that confusion to improve your understanding of how MATLAB handles command/function dual syntaxes :).

Comment: @SamRoberts Precisely - I included it just to show that you *could* do this if you really wanted to (even though you shouldn't) and because I feel bad about leaving single line answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Increment / Decrement operators are not implemented in matlab.

There are reasons to keep a language as simple as possible. For c there are long discussions about [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior) using these operators. Mathworks support also pointed out [similar reasons](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.matlab/2yJP5hjCmqw/UXmJ7Yc1vxgJ) not to implement these operators.